# Проблема при воспроизведении рекламы AdMob Unity

Tags: c#, android, unity3d

Столкнулся с проблемой при воспроизведении рекламного баннера AdMob. Баннерная реклама запускается только в режиме редактирования игры в редакторе Unity. Но когда игра скомпилирована и запущена на телефоне, рекламного баннера нет. Был выключен тестовый режим. Кто-нибудь знает, как это исправить? Некоторые говорили, что надо подождать Может быть, поменять Player Settings или Preferences или что-то другое? У кого была подобная проблема, поделитесь опытом.

Вот код интеграции Admob.

1. Инициализация рекламы:

```
 using System.Collections;
 using System.Collections.Generic;
 using UnityEngine;
 using GoogleMobileAds.Api;
 
 public class InitializeAdMob : MonoBehaviour
 {
     private string appId = "ca-app-pub-xxxxxx~xxxx";
     public void Start()
     {
         // Initialize the Google Mobile Ads SDK.
         MobileAds.Initialize(appId);
     }
 }
```

2. Воспроизведение баннера

```
 using System.Collections;
 using System.Collections.Generic;
 using UnityEngine;
 using GoogleMobileAds.Api;
 
 public class AdsManager : MonoBehaviour
 {
 private string appId = "ca-app-pub-xxxx~xx";
     public BannerView bannerView;
 
     public void Start()
     {
         MobileAds.Initialize(appId);
 
         this.RequestBanner();
     }
     public void RequestBanner()
     {
         string AdUnitId = "ca-app-pub-xxxxxxxxxx/xxxx";
         this.bannerView = new BannerView(AdUnitId, AdSize.Banner, AdPosition.Bottom);
         AdRequest request = new AdRequest.Builder().Build();
         this.bannerView.LoadAd(request);
     }
 }
```

Comment: Может вашему приложению не хватает прав для доступа в интернет.

Comment: Хмм... возможно вы правы. Но только как добавить эти права?

Comment: Начните с того, что укажите в тегах вопроса, что за операционная система.

Comment: Система Андроид

Answer (score 2):

Делай все по инструкции: https://developers.google.com/admob/unity/quick-start
Айди игры должен указываться в scriptable object'е AdMob'а.
Инициализацию нужно проводить только 1 раз.
Еще судя по тому, что ты скрыл айдишники, то ты использовал те айди, которые получил у себя в аккаунте девелопера. ТАК НЕ В КОЕМ СЛУЧАЕ НЕЛЬЗЯ ДЕЛАТЬ ПРИ РАЗРАБОТКЕ. Используй тестовые айди. А перед загрузкой игры в гугл плэй заменишь на свои.
Впрочем все расписано в ссылке выше.